# Is the property of Euclidean domain inherited via surjective ring homomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $f:R \to S$ be surjective ring homomorphism and $R,S$ be integral domains. Could anyone advise me on how to prove/disprove this statement: If $R$ is Euclidean domain, then $S$ is Euclidean domain.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the definition of a Euclidean domain that you use that there is a map $\nu \colon S\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ such that for all $a,b \in S$, $b\neq 0$, there are $q,r\in S$ with $a = qb + r$ and $r = 0$ or $\nu(r) < \nu(b)$, or do you have other requirements?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: In addition, if  $r|s, $ then $\nu(r) \leq \nu(s).$

Comment: Here, $\ker(f)$ must be a prime ideal, and then the gist of Arturo's answer is "look, there are only two types of prime ideals in a Euclidean domain, zero, and the maximal ideals."

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $I := \ker(f)$ is a prime ideal, and $S \cong R / I$.

Comment: Since $R$ is Euclidean domain, so is $R/I.$ So $S$ is also Euclidean domain.

Comment: As currently written, this information is OK but too vague. I guess something more is needed to incorporate being a Euclidean domain. Let me know if you add a clever hint for that half. Incidentally, the solution that [Arturo posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/102521/29335) for this question appears to be almost exactly when he hit 100k rep. I imagined that this was the first time that occurred on math.SE but I haven't been able to confirm it...

Comment: @rschwieb: It's supposed to be a hint, not a proof sketch or a partial solution. :P Arturo's solution is exactly what I had in mind: we have a lot of knowledge about the prime ideals, which in turn tells us a lot about the possible quotient rings, and once we know about the quotient rings, the rest is obvious.

Comment: @Hurkyl : Yes, I know what a hint is and I have given several myself. I am talking about the quality of the hint. If you believe that nonzero primes being maximal in a Euclidean ring is the obvious portion of the question and that the first isomorphism theorem is the part of the question worth hinting on, then I just mean to say that evaluation seems the wrong way around, thinking from a beginner's point of view. Not that you shouldn't say what you said, it's just that it is probably too meager.

Comment: @rschweib: My intent is to get a person thinking about the ideals of a Euclidean domain. I don't want to just give away the key fact: I want to give a person a chance to connect "Ideals are relevant" with "Hey, I know a lot about ideals in a Euclidean ring!", when they might not have given ideals much thought previously; e.g. being focused on the norm. When I can, I prefer to give hints in the form of the sorts of things one should be thinking about when they don't know how to approach a problem, rather than skipping past the initial exploration phase and telling them where to start.

Comment: ... if it doesn't work, that's okay: surely someone else will come along and give away enough of the problem (if not the whole thing) that the OP can figure out the rest. (or, as it turns out, link to a duplicate)